# creating an RPM package from binary file doesn't package the files into an archive

Tags: docker, centos, binaryfiles, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to create an RPM package from node project packaged into a binary file with `pkg`.
I've created an `rpmbuild` skeleton in `/root/rpmbuild`.
The binary package was copied into `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES`.
I've created a `menlolab-runner.service` file in `/root/rpmbuild`.

I'm skipping the `%prep` and `%build` sections in the `.spec` file. During the install section the binary files is copied to `/usr/bin` folder. In the `%post` section the service file is copied to `/etc/systemd/system/`

```
%define version %(cat package.json | jq -r '.version')
%define release 1
%define buildroot /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/

Name: %{name}
Version: %{version}
Release: %{release}
Summary: menlolab-runner

Group: Installation Script
License: MIT
Source0: runner
AutoReqProv: no

%description
The agent deployed on private and public infrastructure to manage tasks.

%global debug_package %{nil}

%prep

%build

%pre
getent group menlolab-runner >/dev/null || groupadd -r menlolab-runner
getent passwd menlolab-runner >/dev/null || useradd -r -g menlolab-runner -G menlolab-runner -d / -s /sbin/nologin -c "menlolab-runner" menlolab-runner

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}

cp runner %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/menlolab-runner
cp /root/rpmbuild/menlolab-runner.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}

%post
systemctl enable %{_unitdir}/menlolab-runner.service
chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/menlolab-runner
mkdir -p '/etc/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/etc/menlolab-runner'
chmod 700 '/etc/menlolab-runner'
mkdir -p '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/'
mkdir -p '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
chmod 700 '/var/lib/menlolab-runner/jobs/'
mkdir -p '/var/log/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/log/menlolab-runner/'
mkdir -p '/var/cache/menlolab-runner/'
chown -R 'menlolab-runner:menlolab-runner' '/var/cache/menlolab-runner/'
groupadd docker
usermod -aG docker menlolab-runner

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%{_bindir}/menlolab-runner
%{_unitdir}/menlolab-runner.service

%defattr(644, menlolab-runner, menlolab-runner, 755)
```

My issue is the fact that `.rpm` contains no files after executing `rpmbuild -ba /path/to/spec/file`.

I think it's because I have no entry in the `%files` section. I'm not sure what to put into this section.  If I add the path to binary file there I receive the following error:

`error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/menlolab-runner-0.2.5a2-1.x86_64/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/runner`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `%install` section you must place files into `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`, so something like:

```
%install
cp runner $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_bindir}/menlolab-runner
```

Subsequently, the `%files` section should list the installed files, relative to the `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`, e.g.:

```
%files
%{_bindir}/menlolab-runner
```

Comment: I get that `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is used to maintain the install hierarchy, and `%{_bindir}` is equivalent to `/usr/bin'. But the resulting command `cp runner /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/menlolab-runner-0.2.5a2-1.x86_64/usr/bin/menlolab-runner` makes no sense to me. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/buildroot.html) will help? The idea behind this is that you are abstracting install directory and for this, you have rpmbuild first install into that buildroot directory, then in the files section you specify which files which were installed to the buildroot needs to be packaged. It's best to learn by looking at existing spec file. Preferrably which installs a service. SystemD unit files should be installed using their own set of macros, e.g. [docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_systemd)

Comment: OK, but where is `menlolab-runner-0.2.5a2-1.x86_64` coming from, shouldn't it be `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/user/bin/menlolab-runner`. I assume the `Sources` is linked to `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES`? Or do I need to provide a full path to `runner ` during `cp`?

Comment: That's just "how it works". See [here](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#buildroots). A buildroot is specific to a package, so one package will have one, and the other will have different.

Comment: Their format is actually dictated by a macro, which you can verify, e.g. `rpm -E %{buildroot}` will yield `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.x86_64`. Actually, I would recommend looking into `mock` for building your package. I typically use a "flat-file" approach whereas all sources and spec file are located in a single directory. With `mock` this is possible. Moreover `mock` allows you to building in a chroot to provide more consistent packaging.

Comment: Don't build RPMs as `root`. *Ever*. It's a very bad practice and this is why - you're stomping all over system files.